# Working of nn.Linear with multiple dimensions

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

PyTorch's `nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)` accepts a tensor of size `(N_batch, N_1, N_2, ..., N_end)`, where `N_end = in_features`. The output is  a tensor of size `(N_batch, N_1, N_2, ..., out_features)`.

It isn't very clear to me how it behaves in the following situations:

1. If `v` is a row, the output will be A^Tv+b
2. If `M` is a matrix, it is treated as a batch of rows, and for every row `v`, A^Tv+b is performed, and then everything is put back into matrix form
3. What if the input tensor is of a higher rank? Say the input tensor has dimensions `(N_batch, 4, 5, 6, 7)`. Is it true that the layer will output a batch of size `N_batch` of `(1, 1, 1, N_out)`-shaped vectors, everything shaped into a `(N_batch, 4, 5, 6, N_out)` tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 1 dimension, the input is vector with dim `in_features`, output is `out_features`. calculated as what you said

for 2 dimensions, the input is `N_batch` vectors with dim `in_features`, output is `N_batch` vectors with dim `out_features`. calculated as what you said

for 3 dimensions, the input is `(N_batch, C, in_features)`, which is `N_batch` matrices, each with `C` rows of vectors with dim `in_features`, output is `N_batch` matrices, each with `C` rows of vectors with dim `out_features`.

If you feel it's hard to think of 3 dimensional case. One simple way is to flatten the shape to `(N_batch * C, in_features)`, so the input becomes `N_batch * C` rows of vectors with dim `in_features` which is the same case as the two dimensional case. This flatten part involves no computation, just rearrange the input.

So in your case 3, its output is `N_batch` of `(3, 4, 5, 6, N_out)` vectors, or after rearrange its `N_batch * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6` vectors with dim `N_out`. your shape with all 1 dims are not correct, since there are only `N_batch * N_out` elements in total.

If you dig into the internal C implementations of pytorch, you can find the `matmul` implementation actually flatten the dimensions as I have described [native matmul](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/31232061aa4779c7db5ebb2d9f89c75cea77c177/aten/src/ATen/native/LinearAlgebra.cpp#L439) which is the exact function used by `nn.Linear`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps then I got the shaping process of the output wrong, however: no matter what the dimension of the input, the linear layer applies the same operation to slices of shape (1,...,N_in) because the linear layer contains a 2-tensor and can only perform a matrix vector multiplication on (1,...,N_in) vectors: is this correct?

Comment: @warm_fish Maybe you can raise a concrete example in your question, maybe just the code you use, and the problem you meet.